# finding mean values at geographic coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a data set that includes measurements of river current taken at specific geographic locations denoted by latitude and longitude.  There is considerable noise in the data, but multiple measurement passes up and down the river.  I am trying to calculate the mean current for a regular grid over the river.  Here is what I am doing

1. read in the data to a dataframe, rounding the latitude and longitude to ~10m resolution (0.0001) degrees.
2. Generate a 10m meshgrid (X,Y) that covers the min to max latitude and longitude.
3. Generate a mean current (Z) for each point on the mesh grid <--- This is where things go wrong.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import descartes
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('./Downloads/current_test/SpdCoach 2182533 20190506 0637AM.csv', skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29], na_values='---')
df['GPS Lon.'] = np.around(df['GPS Lon.'].fillna(method='ffill',limit=50),decimals=4)
df['GPS Lat.'] = np.around(df['GPS Lat.'].fillna(method='ffill',limit=50),decimals=4)
# use the difference in latitude and longitude to determine direction of travel
df['del_lon']=df['GPS Lon.'].diff()
df['del_lat']=df['GPS Lat.'].diff()
df['dir']=np.arctan(df['del_lat']/df['del_lon'])
# use difference between impeller and GPS speed to estimate current
df['current']=np.abs(df['Speed (IMP)'] -df['Speed (GPS)'])

# Set the limits of the meshgrid
x = np.arange(min(df['GPS Lon.']),max(df['GPS Lon.']),0.0001)
y = np.arange(min(df['GPS Lat.']),max(df['GPS Lat.']),0.0001)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.mean(df.current[df['GPS Lon.']==X][df['GPS Lat.']==Y])
```

I tried the statement 
`np.mean(df['current'][df['GPS Lon.']==-71.248][df['GPS Lat.']==42.362])`
and it correctly calculated the mean current for that single Lat/Lon pair.

I expected that when I replaced the numerical values with X and Y that the statement would be evaluated for each point in the mesh grid and calculate the mean value for each.  Most of the values would be zero, except where there is actual data in the file.

I get back the following error.

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1743             # as it will broadcast
   1744             if other.ndim != 0 and len(self) != len(other):
-> 1745                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
   1746 
   1747             res_values = na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other))

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

I am inexperienced with using this type of indexing, so I am probably doing something wrong. I would appreciate it if someone would tell me what it is.

Thanks

Complete Traceback:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9430b088fa85> in <module>
      5 
      6 X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
----> 7 Z = np.mean(df.current[df['GPS Lon.']==X][df['GPS Lat.']==Y])
      8 
      9 cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1743             # as it will broadcast
   1744             if other.ndim != 0 and len(self) != len(other):
-> 1745                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
   1746 
   1747             res_values = na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other))

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

The data frame is defined by the CSV file.  The column names in the data frame are:

```py
['Interval',
 'Distance (GPS)',
 'Distance (IMP)',
 'Elapsed Time',
 'Split (GPS)',
 'Speed (GPS)',
 'Split (IMP)',
 'Speed (IMP)',
 'Stroke Rate',
 'Total Strokes',
 'Distance/Stroke (GPS)',
 'Distance/Stroke (IMP)',
 'Heart Rate',
 'Power',
 'Catch',
 'Slip',
 'Finish',
 'Wash',
 'Force Avg',
 'Work',
 'Force Max',
 'Max Force Angle',
 'GPS Lat.',
 'GPS Lon.',
 'del_lon',
 'del_lat',
 'dir',
 'current',
 'geometry']
```

The intent of the line of code that is throwing the error is to use the Lat,Lon pairs defined in the meshgrid defined by X,Y.  X and Y are numpy arrays dimensioned 282 by 231.

My limited understanding was that this style of indexing would index through each X,Y pair and find matching values in the the data frame df columns 'GPS Lat.' and 'GPS Lon.'

Comment: The traceback snippet only shows the end, it doesn't tell us which line of your code that initiates the problem.

Comment: `df['GPS Lon.']` is probably one dimensional array. `X` on the other hand is a 2D mesh grid. The error comes from `df['GPS Lon.']==X`, and the `Y` counterpart. For people to be able to give you a helping hand, you need to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error occurs on the last line of the code snippet:
Z = np.mean(df.current[df['GPS Lon.']==X][df['GPS Lat.']==Y])

I will try to produce a version of the code that does not require the file read.

Comment: Added complete traceback to the original question

Comment: Updated question to include the column names for the data frame and an explanation of the X,Y arrays.